# Python binding variables

Tags: python, oracle, variables, bind

I am completely lost here:

```py
v_sql = "SELECT widget_name, widget_url FROM widget_calls WHERE widget_name = :widget"
cursor.execute(v_sql, widget=widget_name)
df_wid = pd.read_sql(v_sql, con=connection)
```

Result:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT widget_name, widget_url FROM widget_calls WHERE widget_name = :widget': ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

There is 1 bind variable, :widget, and 1 declaration in the execute.   So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cursor.execute` call and the `pd.read_sql` call are completely unrelated.  You're doing the query twice, and throwing away the first result.  I would delete the useless `cursor.execute`.

And for read_sql, you need:

```
df_wid = pd.read_sql( v_sql, con=connection, params={'widget': widget_name})
```